# Combine map with switchToLatest confuse

Tags: swift, combine

I have a source publisher, and have an another publisher rely source publisher.
This is playground test code for my situation:

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

typealias Image = Int

enum NetError: Error {
    case invalidImage
}

func convertImageToVideo(_ image: Image) -> AnyPublisher<Image, NetError> {
    Future { promise in
        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            if image == 20 {
                promise(.failure(.invalidImage))
            } else {
                promise(.success(image))
            }
        }
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

var image = PassthroughSubject<Image, NetError>()

let subscription = image
    .map { image in
        convertImageToVideo(image)
    }
    .switchToLatest()
    .sink { completion in
        if case let .failure(error) = completion {
            print("Receive error: \(error)")
        }
    } receiveValue: { video in
        print("Receive new video: \(video)")
    }

image.send(0)
image.send(20)
image.send(40)

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    image.send(20)
}

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4) {
    print("Send 50 into image.")
    image.send(50)
}
```

But I only receive one error in console:

```
Receive error: invalidImage
```

This is not ideal, I want continue receive value even if convertImageToVideo method occur an error.
So I change code:

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine
import PlaygroundSupport

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

typealias Image = Int

enum NetError: Error {
    case invalidImage
}

func convertImageToVideo(_ image: Image) -> AnyPublisher<Image, NetError> {
    Future { promise in
        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            if image == 20 {
                promise(.failure(.invalidImage))
            } else {
                promise(.success(image))
            }
        }
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

var image = PassthroughSubject<Image, NetError>()

let subscription = image
    .map { image -> AnyPublisher<Result<Image, NetError>, Never> in
        convertImageToVideo(image)
            .map { video in
                .success(video)
            }
            .catch({ error in
                Just(.failure(error))
            })
            .eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
    .switchToLatest()
    .sink { completion in
        if case let .failure(error) = completion {
            print("Receive error: \(error)")
        }
    } receiveValue: { video in
        print("Receive new video: \(video)")
    }

image.send(0)
image.send(20)
image.send(40)

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    image.send(20)
}

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4) {
    print("Send 50 into image.")
    image.send(50)
}
```

This time output is ideal:

```
Receive new video: failure(__lldb_expr_64.NetError.invalidImage)
Send 50 into image.
Receive new video: success(50)
```

But the error not come from `completion` closure, instead of it come from `new value` closure, I must handle error from `complete` closure and `new value` closure.
Anyone has good idea? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "I must handle error from `complete` closure"? Why do you _have_ to do that? Note that a publisher can fail _at most once_. Once a publisher fails, it "completes" and can't publish anything else. The two things that you want (handle errors in `completion`, and have it still publish values after failing) are mutually exclusive.

Comment: "But the error not come from `completion` closure" <-- Of course, because the publisher has not completed. It still has values to publish, which is what you want, right? If it had come from `completion`, the publisher would have completed, and there would be no more values for you to receive.

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks for your reply, I'm wrong, I'm not understand what error mean before. And for my situation do you have any suggest for code?

Comment: I would just use something similar to your second version of the code, mapping the error to a `Result`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are running into is that when your `image` publisher runs into an error, it finishes the sequence.  What you really want flowing through your sequence is a `Result` saying whether or not each image conversion worked.  To do that, `convertImageToVideo` needs to emit `Result`  values, not just image values.  This leads to some pretty funky looking results from your `Future` because it the future always succeeds and then tells you whether or not the conversion worked.

Here's your code, reworked so the results are flowing through:

import Foundation
import Combine
import PlaygroundSupport

```
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true

typealias Image = Int

enum NetError: Error {
    case invalidImage
}

func convertImageToVideo(_ image: Image) -> AnyPublisher<Result<Image,Error>, Never> {
    Future { promise in
        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
            if image == 20 {
                promise(.success(.failure(NetError.invalidImage)))
            } else {
                promise(.success(.success(image)))
            }
        }
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}

var image = PassthroughSubject<Image, Never>()

let subscription = image
    .flatMap { image in
        convertImageToVideo(image)
    }
    .sink { video in
        switch video {
            case .success(let video):
                print("Receive new video: \(video)")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Receive error: \(error)")
        }
    }

image.send(0)
image.send(20)
image.send(40)

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    image.send(20)
}

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4) {
    print("Send 50 into image.")
    image.send(50)
}
```

And the output is:

```
Receive new video: 0
Receive error: invalidImage
Receive error: invalidImage
Receive new video: 40
Send 50 into image.
Receive new video: 50
```

Comment: That's exactly the answer